ShopWare 6 media-tag delete using rest api
I want to remove a media-tag using the rest api but I don't know how to configure my request.
this is the media-tag I want to remove
{
  
  "mediaId": "1256666666"
  "tagId": "969999999999"
  
}


It's impossible to answer this question. Consult the documentation of the specific API you are interacting with.

To remove a media tag using the REST API, you can use the DELETE method on the /api/media/{mediaId}/tags/{tagId} endpoint. This will remove the specified tag from the media item.
Example request:
DELETE http://<domain>/api/media/1256666666/tags/969999999999
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json
Authorization: Bearer {{auth_token}}

